# How to improve my Lemon Pepper Tuna?

Tags: pepper, tuna

I am a tuna fan. I usually pour it from a tin onto a sandwich without cooking it. Yet there is one kind of tuna that is a problem for me: tinned "lemon pepper" tuna. I don't mind a bit of pepper kick. But a certain well known brand makes lemon pepper tuna that to me is uneatable; the pepper is so strong and abrasive that my mouth is on fire but in a really nasty way.

In my kitchen cupboard I must have about 20 tins of this stuff. I have a tin in my hand now. Ingredients: skipjack tuna, 59%, water. lemon juice, 10%, sunflower oil, black pepper, salt, traces of wheat, milk, egg, crustacea, soy and sesame. [yes, I know I also wonder what formed the 31%]

Is there any way of making this stuff less of a nuclear bomb taste? I have to have any one tin at the time for food safety; I don't keep anything from a tin stored in a fridge. So any idea of having a little bit with something else doesn't work. Is there any strategy? Reducing the taste somehow? Masking it with something else? Reducing acidity if that helps?

I can't throw it to the birds or cats. I have found that animals don't touch tinned fish of any type. Don't know why.

Comment: Why would you need to eat it all at once? Have you opened all 20 tins?

Comment: All the tins are not opened. Having it all at once? That would make Hiroshima into a sneeze by comparison. My plan was to have one a week. Modified somehow to stop it being a weapon of mass destruction.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question, as you state that you have to have it "all at one hit." Further, I'm not sure your question will remain open.  We generally don't allow questions that result is lists of equally valid suggestions.  Reducing the taste, masking it, or reducing acidity are all options.  Maybe focus your question on one main issue, such as, which additional ingredients would reduce the acidity of lemon pepper flavored, tinned, tuna?  Also important to consider: do you eat it straight from the can, or have you tried mixing with other ingredients first?

Comment: I meant having one of the tins at one hit after it's opened; I didn't mean eat all 20.

Comment: Hi, it seems that you're looking for a way to reduce the hot/spicy level, which is covered by the duplicate target (it is about chilli, but the answers simply list typical foods that reduce the hotness sensation). If it is not about the hotness and you're simply asking for things to pair it with, then it would have to be closed for another reason - we don't do pairing questions, because they're opinion based.

Comment: I really doubt that keeping an open tuna can for one night in the fridge makes it unsafe. Especially when it's a significantly processed variety as this seems to be. I've many times eaten tuna that had been open for _a couple of days_ already, though then not without cooking anymore. (I know, cooking is always sufficient to make spoiled food safe, but it certainly kills salmonella etc..)

Answer (score 3):

Create a patè by mixing it with a good store bought mayo (or cream cheese), scallions and parsley. Or drop directly into a big bowl of pasta with some fresh tomatoes&basil and let the steam do it's job.

I don't know, but usually that's how I eat tuna.

Comment: I might go with the pasta route!